# the code under class which implement the interface class does not execute

Tags: java

I have an interface class called intclass. this interface class has a method called mymethod. I have created a class called impclass which implements the interface class, whithin which have the code of mymethod. however I have another method called dmeth which receives the interface intclass as a parameter. the method dmeth is in a different class called dclass. however when I run dclass, the code under mymethod does not execute. I don't understand why.
below is the code:

```
public interface intclass{

public void mymethod(string message);
}


public class impclass 
implements intclass{

public void mymethod(String message){

System.out.println("this is the message"+message);
}

}



public class dclass{

public void dmeth(intclass cl){
....
}

public static main(String[] arg0){
impclass icl =new impclass()
dclass d=new dclass();
d.dmeth(icl);
}
}
```

I have no Idea on what is going wrong.. In case there is even an error concerning the expected parameter for mymethod function, I expect the error, or crashing of the program. but in my case the program run smoothly but the  System.out.println("this is the message"+message); does not print. I tried to put a break in mymethod function and debug, but it was then that I realised mymethod function is not even reached. does anyone has an Idea on what ould be going on

Comment: Well what's the code within `dmeth`? Do you actually call `cl.mymethod`?

Comment: yeah, what does '...' do? I'm guessing it should do 'cl.myMethod(someString)'

Comment: @JonSkeet dmeth only informs a library that it has gotten the intclass

Comment: @Aaron the dmeth receives an interface as a parameter

Comment: Well why were you expecting the message to be printed? Something's got to invoke the method, and nothing that you've shown will do that...

Comment: @eskoba If you expect the method on the interface to be executed, then you must invoke it from within dmeth.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry Jon Skeet. Treading on your toes. I type slow :D

Answer (score 0):

String and string are not the same thing. Be aware of it when you type

```
public interface intclass{
    public void mymethod(string message);
}
```

and

```
public class impclass 
implements intclass{

    public void mymethod(String message){ //Note the Uppercase S
        System.out.println("this is the message"+message);
    }
}
```

Also, your impclass is missing a constructor, and you are not calling the method in any way. Your dmeth should contain

```
public void dmeth(intclass cl){
    cl.mymethod("Message");
}
```

in order to the mymethod to be executed.